# React Motion willEnter and willLeave not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, ecmascript-6, react-motion

I am trying to get react-motion up and running but for some reason the methods `willEnter` and `willLeave` don't seem to be firing when using TransitionMotion.

Currently my setup is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import RecommendationItem from '../typeahead/typeahead_recommendation_block';
import { TransitionMotion, spring } from 'react-motion';

const CALIBRATE = { stiffness: 120, damping: 14 };

export default class Recommendations extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.willEnter = this.willEnter.bind( this );
  this.willLeave = this.willLeave.bind( this );
  this.getStyles = this.getStyles.bind( this );
}

willEnter() {
  console.log( 'Enter' );
  return {
    maxHeight :0,
    opacity: 0
  }
}

willLeave(){
  console.log( 'Leave' );
  return {
    maxHeight : spring(0, CALIBRATE),
    opacity: spring(0, CALIBRATE)
  }
}

getStyles() {
  return {
    maxHeight: spring(500, CALIBRATE),
    opacity: spring(1, CALIBRATE)
  }
}

render() {
  const {
    showRecommendations
  } = this.props

  if( !showRecommendations ) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div className="typeahead-recommendations">
      <TransitionMotion
        willEnter={ this.willEnter }
        willLeave={ this.willLeave }
        styles={
          Object.keys( this.props.recommendations ).map( ( key, i ) => ({
            key : `${key}-${i}`,
            data : {
              title           : key,
              recommendations : this.props.recommendations[key]
            },
            style : this.getStyles()
          }))
        }>
        { (interpolate) =>
          <div>
            {
              interpolate.map(block => {
                if( block.data.recommendations.length && block.key !== 'productSuggestions' ) {
                  return  <div key={ block.key } style={ block.style }>
                            <RecommendationItem
                              title={ block.data.title }
                              recommendations={ block.data.recommendations } />
                          </div>
                }
              })
            }
          </div>
        }
      </TransitionMotion>
    </div>
  )
}
}

Recommendations.displayName = "Recommendations";
```

At the moment the console.logs in willEnter and willLeave are simply never firing. Any advice on why this might be would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are unmounting the whole `TransitionMotion` component. You still need to give the "this.props.recommendations" data to `TransitionMotion`.

For example if you remove an `intem` inside `this.props.recommendations` data, transition motion will kept the item around and still passes it into the children function param. So when you're mapping over these items interpolated styles, you're still producing the same components.

It'll keep interpolating, while checking the deleted current item  value at every frame. Once the deleted item reaches the specified 0, `TransitionMotion` will remove it for good.